# Calendar not linked with classroom

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-classroom

I'm using Google API Ruby Client to create a large number of courses. But, I'm facing an issue that I couldn't find an answer, some courses that have been created does not have a calendar_id, but others do.

So, does exist a limit of calendar_id that an owner can create? For example, I've created 963 courses with an account. But, only 688 has a calendar_id. And courses that doesn't have calendar_id, calendar icon isn't showing on activities section neither calendar.

Comment: Colud you provide more informaiton about what you are doing? Are you tperforming the same request with the same calendar_id? Is there any difference between the courses that do and do not have `calendar_ids`? how do you retrieve the courses and the` calendar-ids`? Please provide the cod eof your requests for reproduction purposes.

Comment: @ziganotschka, no. Each course is created on different request. It's not possible create a calendarId, because its created automaticaly by API. I retrive courses using api method get_course.

Comment: I'n adding my code

Comment: I cannot see your code. By different calendar ids I mean - are zou trying to bind the course to different calendars or to the same one? Or do you not specify a calendar id when creating the course?

Comment: hey, @ziganotschka I find out my issue. It is happening because my account reached calendar limit. I can't create more than 25 calendar in a short period. So, when I create my classroom and classroom api calls calendar(internaly), calendar raises an exception. So I can't create calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened. When an owner account reachs calendar's limit, the calendar will be unavailable, until the account calendar's limit be restored. After 1 week, calendar was available in my classroom. So, there is no other way, only waiting for limit be restored.